# How to reduce StaticLayout delay when using long text

Tags: java, android, textview, epub, staticlayout

I use StaticLayout to paginate my text to create an epub application, and I have a text that has 16,000 lines.

The StaticLayout object is created about 6 seconds later and it's very slow.

How can I reduce this time or is there another way to use StaticLayout instead?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to lay out the whole thing at once. Laying out 16,000 lines of text is *expensive*.  It's going to take a nontrivial amount of time even on a desktop computer with a powerful CPU, and you're trying to do it on a phone.

Instead, take a progressive approach.  Take an approximation of the amount of text you expect might fit in one page - maybe 1000 characters.  You can tweak this value.  Lay that out, see if it's enough, then lay out more if needed.

You can use [`DynamicLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/DynamicLayout) to do this efficiently.  Make sure to pass it an [`Editable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable) when creating it to allow you to update the layout as you add more text.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am working on a project and its deadline is coming to an end. I need a practical example of what you said. My only request is to process a very long text for pagination and display. Thank you @Ryan M.

Comment: Hi @ryan-m . Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid I'm not sufficiently familiar with these APIs to write out a full example without quite a lot of work - it's been a while since I've used them myself.  I hope that my answer points you in the right direction, though.  For DynamicLayout specifically, you may want to look at the framework code that uses it via https://cs.android.com/ - you can easily search the entire Android codebase from there.  Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @Ryan M. I used your solution but it still doesn't work. Should i use EditableTextView ?

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, describe what the exact observed behavior is and what the expected/intended behavior should be. For UI issues, a screenshot or video is usually helpful. Include the exact text of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).